# Without glue, how do DNS servers know the ip of nameservers?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

The domain rspb.org.uk has the nameservers

`ns1.namecity.com.   ['62.128.193.35'] (NO GLUE)   [TTL=172800]`

`ns2.namecity.com.   ['84.22.161.171'] (NO GLUE)   [TTL=172800]`

And on the website intoDNS, there is this warning:

`The parent nameserver ns1.nic.uk is not sending out GLUE for every nameservers listed, meaning he is sending out your nameservers host names without sending the A records of those nameservers. It's ok but you have to know that this will require an extra A lookup that can delay a little the connections to your site.`

In the registrar's settings, I can change these nameservers, but it only allows names, not ip addresses.

My question is, how does the DNS server know the ip address of the nameservers?

I did read somewhere that all nameservers must first be registered in the registry so perhaps an IP address is required during this step. The intoDNS warning mentions "an extra A lookup". *Where* is the DNS looking?

Comment: Lars, you keep asking the same question (http://serverfault.com/questions/525926/where-in-the-dns-process-are-ns-records-used, http://serverfault.com/questions/525877/dns-resolution-for-example-com-can-you-explain), and it keeps getting closed.  Please, **go away and do your homework as voretaq7 suggested, before asking it yet again**.

Comment: @MadHatter Yes I have actually read that book.  I don't have 10 years of experience in system admin though so it doesn't all make sense, and there is nobody in my office senior to me so I can't ask for things to be clarified any other place than here. In all honesty, I'm not being made to feel very welcome here :(

Comment: @MadHatter If you're not happy with my questions could we go on chat instead and sort through my conceptual problems in a more fluid manner?

Comment: I don't normally do that, but just this once, OK.  I'll make a custom room and sit in it for the next five minutes.

Comment: For clarification, Lars and I had a good chat session, and I think he is now much happier about the way things work in recursive-resolution.  He also kindly agreed to accept answers to all three of his questions on the subject to indicate this satisfaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "A lookup" is the standard DNS query that happens when a client needs to know the IP address for a given hostname like `www.example.com`.

In this context, it means you get the info that `ns1.provider.com` is the relevant DNS server for `www.example.com` and without glue records an extra A query for `ns1.provider.com` is necessary. This works exactly like all other queries. In the end, you get an IP address for `ns1.provider.com` and can contact it to get the info you want.

In many cases, like the constellation I outlined below, glue records are not strictly necessary, but it's easy to construct circular dependencies that require glue to break the circle. An example: If you specify `ns1.example.com` as a nameserver for `example.com`, you **must** provide glue for this to work, as `ns1.example.com` could never resolve otherwise.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, but won't ns1.provider.com need its own nameserver too? Then there'll be an infinite loop of looking up nameserver? ...Or if that's not the case, where is the zone file for ns1.provider.com actually kept?

Comment: See my edit: It's easy to construct loops and that's why glue is provided in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Glue is only really needed if the nameservers for a domain are in that same domain, so technically you are fine since yours are in a different domain. As the message says It is just a bit slower, but unless you are Google you do not need to worry about this ;)

How does the DNS server know the ip address of the nameservers? It looks them up in the namecity.com domain. The problem would only arise if the nameservers are in the same domain, thats why you need a glue, to avoid chicken and egg situation.

If you care about this, glue records are usually not called glue in the registrar web interfaces. In mine there is a separate menu entry called "register nameserver", so try clicking around on anything that has nameserver in it ;)

Comment: Thanks this is great. When you say the namecity.com domain, is that a zone file which lists the A records for ns1.namecity.com and ns2.namecity.com?